# In 3d viewport , how can i add object to new collection without it's being unlinked from current collection?

Tags: collections

I want to do 'add'  the selected object to new collection while also keep it still linked to current collection so it will be part of 2 or more collections at the same time? I can do this using outliner, but is there really no faster way to do this in 3d viewport ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**3D View *`object > collection`* Menu**

[image]

*Link the cube that is already in "Collection1" to a new collection, "Collection2"*

***The shortcuts as listed on the menu***

- <kbd>M</kbd> Move to Collection
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> Link to Collection
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> Create New COllection